# Export tables and their column names from Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a postgres DB and I want to export all schemas, the table names and their column names without the actual data to a CSV file or something similar in text. This needs to be exported at once as there is 100s of tables in the DB. Is this possible in Postgres using pgAdmin?

I have tried to export the database but I only could come up with ways to export the names of the tables and columns with the actual data contained in them. I have not being able to export only the schemas, tables and their column names. And I wanted to export the column names for all the tables at once which I was not able to do.

Comment: `pg_dump --schema-only`?

Comment: 1) `select attrelid::regclass AS table_name, attname AS column_name from pg_attribute pa join pg_class pc on pa.attrelid = oid and relkind = 'r' and relnamespace not in('pg_catalog'::regnamespace, 'information_schema'::regnamespace);`?  2) You will need to provide more information in your question about what you expect the output to look like to get a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

`pgAdmin` has access to [psql](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.19/psql_tool.html) so:

```
\pset format csv
\o col_names.csv

SELECT
    attrelid::regclass AS table_name,
    attname AS column_name
FROM
    pg_attribute pa
    JOIN pg_class pc ON pa.attrelid = oid
        AND relkind = 'r'
        AND relnamespace NOT IN ('pg_catalog'::regnamespace, 'information_schema'::regnamespace);

\o

\! head col_names.csv
table_name,column_name
pricing_production,pricegroup
pricing_production,price_id
pricing_production,q_brk_1
pricing_production,q_brk_2
pricing_production,q_brk_3
pricing_production,q_brk_4
pricing_production,q_brk_5
pricing_production,q_brk_6
pricing_production,b_seas_1
```